# Spring boot 2 testing with binary response

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a service that returns a zip file. It works fine in dev/prod, a simple a GET /content/{id}/zip will download the file in my browser.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/content/{id}/zip")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getContentZip(@PathVariable String id) {
        byte[] zip = ...
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"));
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(zip, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
}
```

The problem is with the test:

```
...
MvcResult result = restStudyMockMvc.perform(get("/content/{id}/zip", content.getId()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/zip")).andReturn();

byte[] bytes = result.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();
assertThat(bytes).isNotEmpty();
...
```

It works fine with spring boot 1.5.
Since I've upgraded to spring boot 2. It gives me a "Could not find acceptable representation" exception:

```
11:04:21.244 [main] DEBUG i.o.v.web.ExceptionControllerAdvice - org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:218)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:166)
    at io.osimis.vsol.web.StudyTest.getStudyZip(StudyTest.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: try adding produces to `@GetMapping(value = "/content/{id}/zip",  produces="application/zip")`

Comment: thanks but error is still there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is a little late, but I just had the same error and I found this question while searching for the solution.

In my case the error was that I had manually registered a `HttpMessageConverter` in my test.

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                ...
                .setMessageConverters(myJsonHttpMessageConverter)
                .build();
```

By debugging I found out that the internal logic of Spring Mvc is:

- If there is a converter configured, use only this converter.
- If there is none configured, add all default converters.

Here is the relevant code from `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport`:

```
protected final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
    if (this.messageConverters == null) {
        this.messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        configureMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
        if (this.messageConverters.isEmpty()) {
            addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
        }
        extendMessageConverters(this.messageConverters);
    }
    return this.messageConverters;
}
```

So to solve this you could either **remove your custom converter** so all default converters are used or - if you need it like I did - **add the `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`** in your test setup.

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                ...
                .setMessageConverters(myJsonHttpMessageConverter, new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter())
                .build();
```

Comment: Not late, I was still not able to fix it...Great! Thanks a lot!